# sn74lvc1t45 pullup on the DIR line

Tags: pullup, level

The part sn74lvc1t45 we are sing as an SPI translator.

We usually use B -> A which means DIR goes to ground, however in a new design we are reversing this, and as a result, as per the DS it (being the DIR pin) needs to go to VCC 3v3 - that being said, the default layout PCB design guideline shows an R on this pin - but no mention of its requirements elsewhere.

Any thoughts as to what its value should be? And if so, how were they arrived at?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the design process to calculate a pullup resistor value (applicable to virtually any situation). The general idea is that the *I<sub>I</sub>* leakage current from the chip (from the DIR pin) will induce a voltage drop across the pullup, and that voltage drop should not make the input voltage go below the *V<sub>IH</sub>* high-level input voltage limit indicated in the datasheet.

So:

*R<sub>max</sub>* = (*V<sub>CC<sub>min</sub></sub>* - *V<sub>IH</sub>*) / *I<sub>I<sub>max</sub></sub>*

All the inputs, except *V<sub>CC<sub>min</sub></sub>* are given in the chip datasheet. *V<sub>CC<sub>min</sub></sub>* is dictated by whatever chip you're using as a supply (typically 3.3V - 5%).

Here we go:

*R<sub>max</sub>* = (3.135V - 2V) / 2µA = 567.5 kOhm

**But** this is the maximum value. There is no minimum value required to have the appropriate level applied to the input. So if the DIR input is fixed, you can actually **just tie it directly to the *V<sub>CC</sub>* supply** (just like you could tie it directly to *GND* in the original situation you described).

Note that, in situations when you really need a pullup (e.g. I2C), besides the computation given above that gives the static limit, you typically have to choose a compromise between faster signal rise time (lower pullup values) and lower power consumption (higher pullup values).

Comment: Does the pullup consequently reduce the leakage current?  Does it provide any other benefits?

Comment: @rk It does not reduce the leakage. The leakage spec is used to calculate the value, but that does not change it. Now regarding the benefits: a pullup is useful to induce a "default" logic level but apart from that, it is not beneficial, and has mostly drawbacks: additional power dissipation, more components, ... Use one only if you really have to.

Answer (score 1):

Your task is to ensure DIR pin is having logical 1 relative to VCCA power supply rails. Datasheet says that current leakage through DIR is 1-2 uA, thus if you take 10K resistor voltage drop on the resistor will be 0,02 V, within logical 1 specification.

In reality value of resistor will depend on the following things:

1. if you drive the pin from any output - the value will also depends on leakage currents on that output and drive capability of that output;
2. how steep you want the edge to be when system is powered on. If you do not drive input from any output you theoretically can connect DIR input to VCCA directly.